# How to add role hierarchy in this command

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

**so basically i want to add role hierarchy in this command i am using discord.py 2.0 i checked docs but i am not able to figure out how to exactly do it, pls help me i know its kina dumb question**

```
@app_commands.command(name="ban", description="Ban A User")
    @app_commands.checks.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
    async def MC(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, user: discord.Member, reason: str) -> None:
        await interaction.response.defer(ephemeral=False, thinking=True)

        if reason == None:
            embed = discord.Embed(color=0x55a7f7, timestamp=datetime.datetime.utcnow())
            embed.set_footer(text="If you think this is unfair Join Our Ban appeal Server", icon_url=f"{interaction.user.avatar}")
            embed.add_field(name='Banned', value= f"{user} was Banned \n Reason :- **Not Provided** ") 
            await user.send(embed=embed)
            await user.ban()
            await interaction.followup.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There exists a comparison to check role hierarchy. Members are ranked by their top role, which supports comparisons based on their index in the guild.

```py
if interaction.user.top_role <= user.top_role:
    # the person issuing the command is less than or equal to the person getting banned
    await interaction.followup.send('Hey, you are not allowed to do this.')
# ban them
```